# WCF TimeOut Exception

Tags: wcf, timeoutexception

I have WCF service. I am calling this service from console application. TimeOut for this service is set to default 1 min.

This service calls One function asynchronously whose execution time is not known. But before the execution of this function service TimeOut exception occurs.

Can anybody suggest, How to handle the WCF timeout exception when we are not aware of the time will be taken by the WCF function.

Comment: Either increase the timeout on your service and client else invoke the operation in async mode so that your client doesnt wait for a response from the server